Iterate over a generic iterable without having to clone
I am trying create a struct that stores a copy of an iterable of iterables of u32 and the total of the maximums of the inner iterable. I want to iterate over the passed in data without wasting the memory to clone the input iterable.
I have the code below, but I can only get it to work if I add .clone() between data and .into_iter().
What do I need to do to get this working?
I'm open to the struct instead storing a reference to the iterable as it's intended to be a sorting tag that is displayed after sorting.
use std::collections::{BTreeSet, LinkedList};

struct Totalled<T>
where
    T: IntoIterator + Clone,
    T::Item: IntoIterator<Item = u32>,
{
    data: T,
    total: u32,
}

impl<T> Totalled<T>
where
    T: IntoIterator + Clone,
    T::Item: IntoIterator<Item = u32>,
{
    fn new(data: &T) -> Self {
        let total = data
            .into_iter()
            .map(|inner| inner.into_iter().max().unwrap_or(0))
            .sum();
        Totalled {
            data: data.clone(),
            total,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = LinkedList::new();
    list.push_back(BTreeSet::from([1, 2, 3]));

    let totalled = Totalled::new(&list);
    println!("Total: {}", totalled.total);
    for set in totalled.data {
        println!("{:?}", set);
    }
}


Fixes:

Change data: &T to data: T. Since T is going to be a shared reference, change the bounds to T: IntoIterator + Copy (references can be copied). You're passing in &list, so copying data just copies that reference, it doesn't copy the whole list. Copying a reference is cheap.

Change the inner Item type to &'a u32. Iterating over a reference produces references to the items so we'll be seeing &u32s rather than u32s.

No need for any cloning. data will be implicitly copied when data.into_iter() is called, leaving it available for the Totalled { data, total } line.

Remove the bounds from struct Totalled<T>. It's best practice to omit bounds from struct declarations and just put them on the impl blocks where they're required.


You'll notice that I didn't change main(). Totalled is used exactly the way you wrote it; I just changed how it's implemented.
struct Totalled<T> {
    data: T,
    total: u32,
}

impl<'a, T> Totalled<T>
where
    T: IntoIterator + Copy,
    T::Item: IntoIterator<Item = &'a u32>,
{
    fn new(data: T) -> Self {
        let total = data
            .into_iter()
            .map(|inner| inner.into_iter().max().unwrap_or(&0))
            .sum();
        Totalled { data, total }
    }
}

Playground
If you aren't happy with the generics I'd say ditch them. You could bake the LinkedList and BTreeSet types into Totalled. One of the habits I had to unlearn when I came to Rust was trying too hard to be collection type agnostic. You can end up too generic. I'd probably write concrete types myself:
struct Totalled<'data> {
    data: &'data LinkedList<BTreeSet<u32>>,
    total: u32,
}

impl<'data> Totalled<'data> {
    fn new(data: &'data LinkedList<BTreeSet<u32>>) -> Self {
        let total = data
            .into_iter()
            .map(|inner| inner.into_iter().max().unwrap_or(&0))
            .sum();
        Totalled { data, total }
    }
}

Playground

"data will be implicitly copied". May I query how this is different to cloning the whole list?
Also, the incoming item type must be u32, not &u32, and no standard sequence types implement Copy.
If you look at the main you'll see an example of the expected incoming data type; that can't change.

Not sure why but it compiled this time. Probably because I assumed that you could only pass a reference if the input param was &T, so I stopped it from being a reference and it fail because it didn't have Copy. Is there a way to ensure that the input argument is a reference, since it is now T, not &T? I'm trialing this coming from C++ where it worked by deduction instead of Traits, so I'm trying to get my head around it.
